# What is the correct api document for date().parse()?

Tags: grails, groovy

I googled to see how to create a Date from a string.
One of the pages said to use the parse() method like this

`def date = Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', '1/1/2020')`

I am using Grails 4.03. The Grails document page says this is using Groovy 2.5.6. So, this does not work. To make this work, I need to add

`implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:3.0.9'` to the build.gradle file.

I am looking for the document for the parse() method.

None of these documents below tells me how to use the parse() method.

Which document should be the correct document for this parse() method?

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.6/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.6/html/gapi/

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Comment: You may like to refer to https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-string-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/apache/groovy/dateutil/extensions/DateUtilStaticExtensions.html#parse(java.util.Date,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

or groovy version prior to 2.5 still contains this method description

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.4.6/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

call should be like this because `parse` is a static method

```
def date = Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', '1/1/2020')
```

Comment: Thx.  Your link points to a different package org.apache.groovy.  Is this the same as the org.codehaus.groovy package?  I can't find the doc because I look under the org.codehaus.groovy package.  There is no dateutil under the org.codehaus.groovy page.

Comment: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-dateutil/3.0.9/

Comment: `org.codehaus.groovy` is an artifact group id and not a package name. whole groovy published under this group id. you could download `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:3.0.9` jar artifact and check the package name in it.

Comment: Ok thx.  So, this link should be the correct document I am looking for.  https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.6/html/api/org/apache/groovy/dateutil/extensions/DateUtilStaticExtensions.html It is 2.5.6 and under the ```org.apache.groovy.dateutil.extensions``` package.

Comment: I also corrected my code from ```def date = new Date().parse(...)``` to ```def date = Date.parse(...)``` in my question.  Both works without any error though.